question about elementary embeddings
This is a problem from Chang&Keisler that I am not sure how to get a start at - so any hints would be appreciated:
Let $U=\langle(0,1),\leq\rangle$ and $B=\langle[0,1),\leq\rangle$, let $U'$ be the union of $\aleph_1$ disjoint copies of $U$ and $\aleph_0$ disjoint copies of $B$ and let $B'$ be the union of $\aleph_0$ copies of $U$ and $\aleph_1$ copies of $B$. Show that $U'$ and $B'$ are isomorphically (but not elementarily) embedded in each other.

That $U’$ and $B’$ embed into each other isomorphically simply follows from that $U$ and $B$ embed into each other isomorphically.
Now, to see that $B’$ does not embed into $U’$ elementarily, we note that there are $\aleph_1$ many elements of $B’$ satisfying the first-order property that they are minimal (namely, $0$ in those $\aleph_1$ many copies of $B$). Hence, any elementary embedding $B’ \to U’$ will send those $\aleph_1$ many minimal elements to $\aleph_1$ many minimal elements in $U’$, but the latter only has $\aleph_0$ many minimal elements.
To see that $U’$ does not embed into $B’$ elementarily, we note that there are $\aleph_1$ many elements of $U’$ satisfying the first-order property that they are pairwise incomparable and none of them majorize a minimal element (for example, $\frac{1}{2}$ in those $\aleph_1$ many copies of $U$). Hence, any elementary embedding $U’ \to B’$ will send those $\aleph_1$ many elements to $\aleph_1$ many elements of $B’$ that are pairwise incomparable and none of them majorize a minimal element. But such $\aleph_1$ many elements do not exist in $B’$.
